actions that cover the possibility of failure of said action
a method comprising:
a) identifying entities in the database having certain conditions;
b) sending the entities to the client's device;

Questions:

If zero entity in the database has those conditions, will step (a) be considered performed?
If zero entity in the database has those conditions, is step (b) even valid? Will step (b) be considered performed?


Would the following alteration work better to convey the intent:
a method comprising:
a) attempting to identify entities in the database having certain conditions;
b) in response to successfully identifying the entities, sending the entities to the client's device;

I would go for identifying (or determining or calculating) a "set" or "list" or "bag" of database entities and sending (a computer-readable representation of) said set/list/bag.
This is how most protocols work; some kind of response must be sent back even if no entities were selected by the query just in order to allow the client to know that there were no matches and it can proceed on that basis rather than waiting for results indefinitely.
The case in which nothing was found and nothing was sent does not need to be covered by the claim; it is usually sufficient to have a claim to cases in which something was found and sent. (For a method at least - for a machine one must pay greater attention to what the claim requires when nothing was found.)

So you agree that my first claim does require something to be found in order for the step to be considered performed?

No, the identifying/determining/calculating step is performed even if nothing is found. There must be specifics to it that render it novel and unobvious to perform. One can find nothing by different methods; that's fine a competitor is free to find nothing by other methods without infringing same as the prior art might find nothing by other methods without anticipating.

I think he means step b in the first version where if nothing is identified this nothing sent the step is not executed.

@GeorgeWhite I meant both steps.

As the answer already says, I recommend to not worry about the performance of (b) when nothing was found. It is sufficient to capture the infringers based on the instances in which something was found. (Except perhaps there might be a slight indefiniteness issue to worry about with your original wording.)

The second version is better than the first version.
A smaller change might be better. Every word in a claim can be subject to an interpretation. Sometimes the fewer the better.
a) identifying entities in the database having certain conditions;
b) sending identified entities to the client's device;
You could add “any” before identified but any could mean all and there might be a way around the claim if every query identified a dummy entities that was not sent.

Would this version be even better?
"in response to having successfully identified the entities, sending the entities to the client's device;"
